# Jira Zephyr Integration with Webdriver IO

Tags: jira, webdriver-io, jira-zephyr

Being completely new to webdriver IO, wondering how do I update an existing test cycle (with specific name format) in Jira. I am running the test suite on 3 different browsers and have separate test cycles for these cycles in Jira. After execution, I want the suite to update these cycles with the status and screenshots for each browsers respectively. ANy help is much appreciated.

PS: At the moment I have a function that creates a new test cycle for each execution.

Answer (score 0):

there are no plugins for zephyr scale integration till now, but you can use zephyr api to update your execution results .

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Nodejs lib for creating testruns and reporting results back to Zephyr scale.

Maybe they can help you on your way.

If you have any questions or feedback, let me know!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dbouckaert/zephyr-scale-reporter

Example: get all testcases for a project

```
/**
 * This function will get all testcases for a certain project and add them to variables.testCasesArray
 * @returns {void}
 */
export const getAllTestcases = async (): Promise<void> => {
  await request(variables.url)
    .get(`/rest/tests/1.0/project/${variables.projectId}/testcases`)
    .auth(variables.username, variables.password)
    .expect(200)
    .then((res) => {
      variables.testCasesArray = res.body.testCases;
    });
};
```